# Define a method in interface which takes n parameters

Tags: c#

I am trying to define an interface and classes which implement the interface as below. The method defined in the interface accepts a string as argument where myClass2 implementation of the method `Execute` takes 2 arguments which doesn't follow the interface definition.

That's the problem. How could I define a method within an interface which takes n number of parameters of various type?

Please advice. Thanks.

```
public interface MyInterface
{
     void Execute(string a);
}

public class myClass1 : MyInterface
{
     public void Execute(string a)
     {
        Console.WriteLine(a);
     }
}

public class myClass2 : MyInterface
{
     public void Execute(string a, int b)
     {
          Console.WriteLine(a);
          Console.WriteLine(b.ToString());
     }

}
```

EDIT: I am thinking of another approach. I appreciate if someone could tell me if this will be a better design.

```
public interface IParameter
{
    Type ParameterType { get; set; }
    string Name { get; set; }
    object Value { get; set; }
}

public interface MyInterface 
{
     void Execute(Recordset recordSet, List<IParameter> listParams);
}

public class MyClass : MyInterface
{
      public void Execute(Recordset recordSet, List<IParameter> listParams)
      {

      }
}
```

I am passing a list of IParameter which holds all the required parameters which need to be sent.

Comment: Something smells here. What led you to this design?

Comment: If your class needs to have a method with two parameter, you have to have that same method signature (`Execute` with two parameters) in your interface as well. There's no magic method to make this here happen....

Comment: @David: You can look at the comment for Jon. This will give you an idea what I am trying to achieve.

Comment: I think the first step in designing this is to work out which participent owns each piece of information. It sounds like each different plug in has to have different parameters that only the plug in knows about. You can't ask the framework to know about the different implementation requirements of the plug ins.in knows about. You can't ask the framework to know about the different implementation requirements of the plug ins.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

How would the caller know how to call the method, if the interface didn't fix the parameter types?

The closest you can can would be:

```
public interface MyInterface
{
     void Execute(params object[] args);
}
```

Implementations of the interface would have to then *deal* with any number of arguments being passed in though - you couldn't have an implementation which *only* handled a single `int` parameter, although it could of course throw an exception if `args` contains anything *other than* a single `int` value.

EDIT: Just to be clear, this would rarely be a good design. In some *very weakly typed* scenarios it may be appropriate, but otherwise, usually it would be worth trying to find something better.

If you can give more information about what you're trying to do, we may be able to help you more.

Comment: I think your answer would be improved if you made it clear that using the code you present is very likely a bad idea. You might mislead the questioner as it stands.

Comment: I am designing  technical indicators. i.e. Simple Moving Average , Exponential Moving Average and etc. All of the indicators take recordset as mandotary parameter. Some of the indicators might take periods as an additional parameter and others take periods and name as additional parameters. I am trying to design a plugin type host which expose a method thru interface. Anyone can build their own indicator which can be a plug-in component for the host. I may have approached wrongly for the design. As I said, each indicator has a different number and type of parameters which can be passed to

Comment: @Alan: Yes, I think you probably *have* got the design wrong. Interfaces are used to decouple the caller from the precise thing it's calling. That's fine if any caller can call any implementation - but in this case it sounds like that's not the case.

Comment: @Jon: Thanks. Is there any other approach that you feel worth looking at?

Comment: @Alan: We don't really know enough about what you're doing - how would you intend to match up different callers to the different indicators?

Comment: @Jon: I am planning to use dependency injection to match up different callers to the indicators via Structure Map.

Comment: @Alan: So what would you expect to happen if you gave an indicator to a caller which gave it the wrong kind of data? I think it would be a good idea to *avoid* that situation, which is something that having a different interface per "kind of indicator" would give you.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this for good reason. Different implementations of interfaces are meant to be used interchangeably. Your proposed design violates this principle. If you want help solving the conflict I think you need to explain what led you to this design.

Answer (score 1):

So you're defining your interface as

```
public interface MyInterface
{
    void Execute(string a);
}
```

and attempting to implement it as

```
public void Execute(string a, int b)
{
    ...
}
```

That won't work - you're declaring one interface, and attempting to define something else.

What might work (and I can't tell based on your post thus far) is explicit interface implementation - that is, your concrete object could expose an Execute(string, int) method and explicitly implement your interface method.  Something like

```
public class myClass2 : MyInterface
{
    public void Execute(string a, int b)
    {
        ...
    }

    void MyInterface.Execute(string a)
    {
        ...
    }
}
```

That said, I'd *strongly* advise that you rethink this design.  The entire point of interfaces is that they expose a common programmatic surface to the rest of your code - breaking that contract stinks to high heaven, in terms of code-smells.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with weakly typed approach. E.g., you could define an interface that takes objects array:

```
public intrface MyInterface
{
  void Execute(params object[] args);
}
```

And than you can call any of your concrete class with any arguments:

```
myClass.Execute("string", 1);
```

But in this case you violate the main purpose of interfaces, inheritance and compile-time checks.

Another way to implement this is to achieve this is to encapsulate all parameters in additional class hierarchy:

```
class CommandData
{
  public string StringData {get; set;}
}

class ExtendedCommandData : CommandData
{
  public int I {get;set;}
}

interface IMyInterface
{
  public void Execute(CommandData commandData);
}

class MyClass1 : IMyInterface
{
  public void Execute(CommandData commandData);
}

class MyClass2 : IMyInterface
{
  // Lets impelment this interface explicitely
  void IMyInterface.Execute(CommandData commandData)
  {
  }

  void Execute(ExtendedCommandData extendedData)
  {
    // now we can access to string and int parameter
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @Jon answer:  considering that you are implementing an Interface, so you are architect, just don't use an interface but simple base class with  overloaded virtual functions and in every concrete class ocerride it in a way you prefer.

**EDIT:** 
I mean something like this: instead of using interface declare base class, a *pseudocode!*

```
public class MyCoolBase // a base CLASS and not interface
{
     public virtual void Execute(string a)
     {
        //empty, or NotImplementedException, base on design decision
     }

     public virtual void Execute(double b)
     {
        //empty, or NotImplementedException, base on design decision
     }
     public virtual void Execute(int a, int b)
     {
        //empty, or NotImplementedException, base on design decision
     }
}

public class MyCoolChildOne : MyCoolBase  
{
     public override void Execute(string a)
     {
        //concrete implementation
     }
}

public class MyCoolChildTwo : MyCoolBase  
{
     public override void Execute(int a, int b)
     {
        //concrete implementation
     }
}
```

and so on...

**Bad:** When you do something like this in the code

```
MyCoolBase myCoolBase = new MyCoolChildOne ();

myCoolBase...?(); // should be really sure which function you're going to call on this line
```

**Good:** You have strong types management, and no more `object[]` arrays, or multiple inheritance from more then one interface which you **must** override, instead in this case you cam even avoid it, even if I think it's not so good idea.

By the way, like geeks here said, I don't think your  architecture is very reliable, there should be some other solution around for you. We just try to find out the best choice looking on code and question, but real problem can know only you.

Hope this helps.

Regards.

Comment: How does this solve the problem (at all)?  How does it solve it any differently than what's already been proposed?

Comment: @merlyn it avoids to declare just array of objects but type safe overloaded functions in base class.

Comment: Oh.  It sounded like you were trying to say "do what Jon did, but don't use an interface - use a class".  Can you provide a code sample?  It would clear up your answer quite a bit.

Comment: @morgan sorry no, writing from mobile now and writing code from here I will become simply mad. But idea is pretty simple , I believe, declare base class and put inside all overloaded functions you need like virtuals ones, even with empty body, and after in any concrete implementation implement the cide you need.

Comment: @morgan jon's solution provides a single function with collection of objects like a parameter, mine, instead, functions with strong type parameters, but virtuals ones.

Comment: I got it after you said "type safe overload".  I just think you should edit the answer to clarify your meaning, when you get a chance.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, this might be a great use case for generics.

You define the minimum required parameters as properties of an interface, then inherit where more parameters are required.

Looks quite silly when you're only using 1 parameter in the base interface, but of course this concept could be expanded to more complex types.

```
public interface MyInterface<T> where T : ParamA
{
  void Execute(T paramA);
}

public interface ParamA
{
  string ParameterA { get; }
}

public class myClass1 : MyInterface<myClass1.myParamA>
{
  public class myParamA : ParamA
  {
    public string ParameterA { get; set; }
  }

  public void Execute(myParamA a)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(a.ParameterA);
  }
}

public class myClass2 : MyInterface<myClass2.myParamsAb>
{
  public class myParamsAb : ParamA
  {
    public string ParameterA { get; set; }
    public int ParameterB { get; set; }
  }

  public void Execute(myParamsAb ab)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(ab.ParameterA);
    Console.WriteLine(ab.ParameterB.ToString());
  }
}
```